# Idiom for doing a job totally carelessly

Tags: idiom-requests

What is the idiom that best describes someone doing his job carelessly as if he looks like fed up with his job or needs to get fired?

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266443/alternative-idiom-to-phone-it-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ideas:

***Going through the motions***

***Doing the bare minimum***

***Phoning it in***

***Can hardly be bothered***

***Checked out***

Or you could say that someone's work has become

***Mechanical***

***Slipshod***

***Cursory***

Comment: The terms/phrases you suggest are good, but you could improve your answer by adding references.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but they just came off the top of my head. So consider the references _me, myself and I_.

Answer (score 3):

"[To slack off](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slack-off)", meaning to work less hard than is usual or necessary,  is another possibility. Although Cambridge lists it as American English, I have little doubt it is well understood by global English speakers. "Slack" can also be used by itself, as for example in  "he's so slack at work it's a wonder he hasn't been fired yet".

Other useful words, probably more standard English than idiomatic, include

- [lackadaisical](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lackadaisical): showing little enthusiasm or effort (Cambridge), and
- [perfunctory](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perfunctory): done quickly without care or interest (Cambridge).