# PC workplace term for personality type of someone who has no interest in doing their job

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to describe personality types in the workplace. You get type A personality (perfectionist) and type B (social, enthusiastic).

What do you call the personality type who got a job for political reasons such as nepotism, brownnoser, sucking up but they have no interest in doing their job properly? is there a politically correct/academic/research paper term to call this personality type? I want to say in my company you get type A personality and type ___, the latter has no interest in being a craftsman but just gamified the system for the sake of earning an income. Basically, someone with no skill, no interest in gaining a skill, just have the title.

Comment: He (and/or his actual job) might be called a [***seat-warmer.***](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/seat-warmer.2314681/) Also [***time-server***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/time-server) *- a person who does not work very hard at their job, and who is just waiting until they reach the age at which they can stop work*.

Comment: Verbs for the behaviour type are found at the [word or phrase ... to describe doing something merely to pass the criteria in place](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403908/word-elegant-phrase-or-slang-to-describe-doing-something-merely-to-pass-the-cri/403925#403925) thread (eg 'going through the motions').

Comment: Such people could be called ‘favoured’, as they are given an advantage which is unfair to others. ‘Work-shy’ captures their disinclination to work. Waiting for someone to share a term that covers both attributes.

Comment: [**Sinecurist**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sinecurist)?

Comment: I think it would be hard to come up with a PC term, simply because acknowledging this may be inappropriate.